# deleting column containing white spaces in mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-error-1064

I was wondering how do I drop a column, containing spaces, in mysql.
Tried the following, and got the following exceptions:

```
alter table test17 drop column [added column2];
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[added column2]' at line 1

alter table test17 drop column 'added column2';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''added column2'' at line 1

alter table test17 drop column (added column2);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(added column2)' at line 1
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Does column name contains space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using back ticks ("`") to quote your column name.

```
ALTER TABLE test17 DROP COLUMN `added column2`;
```

OR

Without COLUMN word

```
ALTER TABLE test17 DROP `added column2`;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, column name with space is BAD PRACTICE. Then, if you really want to drop a column, use backtick instead:

```
ALTER TABLE test17 DROP COLUMN `added_column2`;
```

Comment: Yea that was a mistake... Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alter table test17 drop column `added column2`;
```

Note that the quote characters are tilted left.

By the way, if you include spaces as part of identifier names (e.g. functions, procedures, tables, columns, etc.), that is a very, **VERY** bad practice.

Comment: Thanks! beginners mistake:/

Comment: Indeed :-). By the way, if you use normal naming methods (e.g. `ThisIsColumn_5` or the like, using solely alphanumeric characters and `_`, starting with a letter), you spare yourself from enclosing identifiers in titled quote signs. For instance, in your case it would look: `alter table test17 drop column added_column2;`. Last, my answer was the very first but you selected to mark other as THE answer...

Comment: Well thanks..I don't know I used the other guy's answer (without the column) so I thought you pick the answer you actually use eventually...